# Linguagem golang

Tags: golang

Estou entrando no mercado agora, e estou realizando estágio em uma empresa de desenvolvimento.

Estou com umas dúvidas sobre a linguagem do Google, a Golang (Go), são elas:

1. Existe alguma coisa pronta em relação a criptografia AES e RSA para a linguagem Go?
2. Existe uma maneira de fazer compressão da área de dados na linguagem Go, sem usar Tazgz?
3. Alguém já fez cache na linguagem Go, com REDIS?

Comment: > Alguém já fez cache na linguagem Go, com REDIS? Eu já fiz em alguns projetos, é bem simples.
Eu recomendo usar a biblioteca [go-redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) ela é bem tranquila de usar, tem uma boa documentação, e é uma das recomendadas pelo próprio Redis :).

Comment: Dê uma olhada na biblioteca padrão Crypto.
https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/. Sobre compressão, bom, existe esse pacote https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata que transforma em binário qualquer tipo de dado e o pacote https://golang.org/pkg/compress/

Comment: 1-
Recentemente eu tive um problema de como gerar chaves rsa para serem válidas para fazer a validação com o jwt. Eu consegui obter o resultado que queria. Segue o link do projeto. [Heimdall](https://github.com/rafaelgfirmino/heimdall/blob/master/key/key.go)

Comment: Oi, para fazer cache com Redis pode utilizar uma libreria pronto dos creadores de go-redis: https://github.com/go-redis/cache tem o codigo de ejemplo no README.

Answer (score 3):

*Não posso responder todas as perguntas...*

> Existe alguma coisa pronta em relação a criptografia AES e RSA para a linguagem Go?

Sim, na verdade muito mais do que apenas RSA e AES. Mas, sobre o AES ele também [suporta AES-GCM](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/), *que é um AEAD*, além de vários outros métodos de cifra de bloco.

Em resumo [veja isto](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/) e [este aqui](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto) que é complementar.

Este último adiciona o suporte para [NaCl](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box), como consequência também permite usar chacha20poly1305, salsa20. Além de poder usar outras coisas já prontas, como [openpgp](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp) e o [tls](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/).

Logicamente ele também oferece um CSPRNG. Também conta com vários tipos algoritmos de hashing (desde MD4 até SHA-3 e BLAKE2), além de suporte para derivações de chaves (como BCrypt, Scrypt, PBKDF2, HKDF...).

Um ponto importante é que infelizmente a maior parte das implementações não são constant-time, isso é mencionado publicamente na página. Por essa razão eles não podem ser considerados seguros de maneira geral. Além disso a implementação do RSA suportar PKCS#1 1.5, [o que não é bom](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5), mas ao menos lhe da a possibilidade de usar OAEP.

Se quiser ir mais fundo e usar algum HSM ou ao menos um Amazon KMS, [ele já oferece suporte para o Golang](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/kms/).

Answer (score 1):

> Existe alguma coisa pronta em relação a criptografia AES e RSA para a
>   linguagem Go?

Sim, em relação a criptografia o GoLang já está de igual pra igual com linguagens que estão a bem mais tempo no mercado.

Segue um print de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte : [golang.org](https://golang.org/src/crypto/)

Aconselho ler a documentação e qualquer dúvida que tiver volte e crie uma pergunta sobre.

> Existe uma maneira de fazer compressão da área de dados na linguagem Go, sem usar Tazgz?

Sim, pode utilizar: `import "archive/zip`

> Alguém já fez cache na linguagem Go, com REDIS?

Com toda certeza, muitos utilizam a biblioteca chamada Go-Redis.

Obtendo : `go get -u github.com/go-redis/redis`

Utilizando: `import "github.com/go-redis/redis"`

[Go-Redis Github](https://github.com/go-redis/redis)